# Add only item as a List

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

```
class Nameday
{
    public class Date
    {
        public int mm;
        public int dd;

        public Date(int get_mm, int get_dd)
        {
            mm = get_mm;
            dd = get_dd;
        }
    }

Dictionary<string, List<Date>> name_day = new Dictionary<string, List<Date>>();
```

To be able to to add a new value i have to define a List like this:

```
List<Date> tmp = new List<Date>();
tmp.Add(new Date(10, 14));
name_day.Add(item, tmp);
```

It works fine but i would like to leave the "tmp" part to something like this:

```
name_day.Add(item, new Date(mm,dd).ToList());
```

Can i do it?

Comment: You'll get more specific answers if you add a language tag such as either `c#` or `java`.

Comment: For C#, you can use  `List<Date> tmp = new List<Date> { new Date(10, 14) };`. Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

Comment: Or all in one line: `name_day.Add(item, new List<Date> { new Date(10, 14) });`

Comment: May I ask why do you name_day is a `Dictionary<string, List<Date>>` since it looks like the lists contain only one element? Why not a `Dictionary<string, Date>`...unless you plan to add new Date instances to the lists?

Comment: Summarize it was took of my homework. I have a criterion to use Dictionary. I have another Dictionary(day_name<Date,string[]>. In the task there are different kind of questions fe. In what day(S) we celebrate xy' (I think it's easier to find the name_day List because the Value tells the dates. Another question ask that in 10.14 Who or WHOSE day name is so it enumarate the names.
If u have any advice please tell me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions I see to make a oneliner solution similar to the one you expect:

1. Without additional code, you can instantiate directly the List with its item.

   ```
   name_day.Add(item, new List<Date>{new Date(mm,dd)});
   ```
2. Or you can implement a `ToList` method in `Date`...but it's rather useless

   ```
   public List<Date> ToList() => new List<Date> { this };
   ```

   then as you expected

   ```
   name_day.Add(item, new Date(mm,dd).ToList());
   ```

   **EDIT** a better solution is using a method extension as described in weichch's answer
3. Another way is using an extension method on the `Dictionary`

   ```
   public static class DictionaryExtensions
   {
       public static void Add(this Dictionary<string, List<Date>> dict,string key, Date date)
       {
           dict.Add(key, new List<Date>{ date });
       }
   }

   //...and then use it that way
   name_day.Add(item, new Date(mm,dd)
   ```

   ...and you can also add code to check if there is already a list corresponding to the same key and add it....

Answer (score 0):

*See comments under this answer for reason why extension method :)*

You can create an extension method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

```
public static class DataExtensions
{
    public static List<Date> ToList(this Date date)
    {
        return new List<Date> { date };
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
name_day.Add(item, new Date(mm,dd).ToList());
```

Comment: Why to you want to create en extension method in that case?

Comment: @C.Champagne The OP wants `new Date(mm,dd).ToList()`, but it doesn't make sense to have `ToList` method defined by a `Date`? How can a date be converted to a list? That's why it was an extension method. BUT, there's really no need to create a method if the OP did not ask for one :)

Comment: You are absolutely right, adding a method in the class is a bit polluting it but in fact I think that no additional method or method extension in necessary or even a bit useful in this case.

Comment: Depends if typing `new List<Date> { new Date() }` is too much. If I need to type a lot of that, I'd rather have a useless extension method for me to save some typing. However, I know to some people typing is not a problem, so up to people I guess :)

Comment: You are right again and the gain of readability is another improvement but honestly in this case you really need to type it a lot to compensate the the class you create and there might be better solutions.

Comment: Yep, lots of possibilities here :) might also create a helper / extension method to `Dictionary<string, List<Date>>` to be able to add like this `Add(this Dictionary<string, List<Date>> dic, string key, Date date)` :)

Comment: That is precisely what I thought! I was adapting my answer when you added your comment :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works to but i would rather C.Champagne's :)

Comment: @gaborbozo no problem the accepted answer has more information you need.